# How can I read a semi-colon delimited log file in R?

Tags: r, delimiter, logfile

I am currently working with a raw data set that, when downloaded from our device, outputs in a log file with values delimited with a semi-colon.

I am simply trying to load this data into r so I can put it onto a dataframe and analyze from there. However, as it is a log file I can't use read_csv or read_delim. When I use read_log, there is no input where I can define the delimiter, and as such my columns are being misread and I am receiving error messages since r is not recognizing ; as a delimiter in the file.

I have been unable to find any other instances of people using delimited log files with r, but I am trying to make the code work before I resign to uploading it into excel (I don't want to do this, both because the files have a lot of associated data and my computer runs excel very slowly). Does anyone have any suggestions of functions I could use to load the semi-colon delimited log file?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use `read.delim` (or `readr::read_delim`, or anything else similar)? What doesn't work about setting `sep = ";"`? The base `read.csv2` even has semicolons as the default delimeter

Answer (score 1):

You could use `data.table::fread()`. `fread`automatically recognizes most delimiters very reliable and reads most file types like *.csv, *.txt etc.
If your facing a situation where it doesn't guess the right delimiter, you can define it by setting the option`fread(your_file, sep=";"`). But it won't be necessary in your case.

I've creates a file named `your_file` without any extension and the following content:

`Text1;Text2;Text3;Text4`

And now imported it to R:

```
library(data.table)

df = fread("your_file", header=FALSE)
```

**Output:**

```
> df
      V1    V2    V3    V4
1: Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4
```